truffle migrate only compiles contracts
I tried using truffle migrate--network development but it only compiles the contracts as so:
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\SimpleStorage.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\SimpleStorage.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive - Monash University\FYP A\MyEthereumProject\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.21+commit.d9974bed.Emscripten.clang
Network up to date.

I've also tried truffle console --network development and migrate --reset but it still only compiles the contracts. There are no transactions recorded in the transactions tab on Ganache either.
My truffle-config file is as such:
 development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
      gas: 3000000
    },

(sorry I couldn't paste images here)

Truffle has been deprecated for a while I suggest to use another tools like hardhat or forge. Check your deployment scripts they seem to be missing.
